# Surly Ogre thru axle fork options

Tags: wheels, quick-release, through-axle

I just picked up a Surly Ogre frame and I already have a set of 12mm thru axle wheels (12x142 rear, 12x100 front). The Ogre rear dropout is thru axle ready, but I'm trying to figure out my options for the fork (I don't have a fork yet):

1) Find a 12mm through axle touring fork (would want IS disk mounts, fender and rack mounts, and geometry similar to that of the [Ogre fork](https://surlybikes.com/parts/ogre_fork), I think its ~448mm axle to crown, non-suspension corrected). This seems like a good way to go, but I'm having trouble finding a fork that fits these requirements.

2) Get a Surly Ogre fork, and install the front wheel with a [12mm to quick release adapter](https://www.ebay.com/itm/MTB-Tools-Road-Bike-12mm-x-100mm-Thru-Axle-to-Standard-5mm-QR-Wheel-Adapter-/252351137843). I think this might be a good option given that the Ogre fork meets all my requirements already and allows me to use the wheel I already have. My only worry is whether using the adapter negates the point of a thru axle, or if it will be unsafe (I have no idea whether this is true)

3) Get a QR front wheel compatible with the Ogre fork. (don't want to have to spend more money to replace a wheel I have already)

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: What kind of front hub do you have? Some hubs (e.g., White Industries, DT Swiss) are easily configurable to different axle diameters. That might greatly open up your fork options

Comment: Also, your axle-to-crown number is way off

Comment: Looking around the other QPB brands (Salsa, Whisky), I'm really hoping you can convert that front hub to 15x100

Comment: What I would do is contact Surly and ask what they can recommend. You probably are not the first to want to put a TA fork on an Ogre frame.

Comment: Ah yes, 448mm is what I meant. It's a Specialized wheelset that comes stock with one of their bikes, it seems like the hubs are custom? I'm not sure: https://www.lfgss.com/conversations/302428/

Contacting Surly is a good idea, I'll see what they have to say

Comment: I contacted Surly and they also recommended a quick release adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 12mm thru axle to 9mm thru bolt adapter (literally just a 100mm long tube that is 12mm OD and 9mm ID) can provide a strong, stiff, and tool-free interface, and I believe is available from the same source as the 12 to 5mm adapter you are considering. In my experience, thru bolts (e.g., the tool free version available from DT Swiss) are much stronger than a hollow 9mm axle with 5mm qr skewer (I have broken a few), and have every advantage of a thru axle.  This would allow you to use the Ogre fork, or any of a number of QR-style forks.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any suggestion for good adapter brands that you've had success with?

Comment: I believe that the eBay seller linked in your question has them.

Comment: Ok, so you think something like [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/MTB-Tools-Road-Bike-12mm-Thru-Axle-to-9mm-Quick-Release-for-100mm-Fork-/263176412442) with the [DT swiss thru bolt](https://www.amazon.com/DT-Swiss-Aluminum-Lever-9x100mm/dp/B004N9DL64/ref=cm_wl_huc_item) would be good?

Comment: Yep, i think that would be perfect